# DB2 SQL to aggregate value for months with no gaps

Tags: db2

I have 2 tables which I need to join against, along with a table that is generated inline using WITH. The WITH is a daterange, and I need to display all rows from 1 table for all months, even where no data exists in the 2nd table.

This is the data within the tables :

Table **REFERRAL_GROUPINGS**

```
referral_group
--------------
VER
FRD
FCC
```

Table **DATA_VALUES**

```
referral_group | task_date  | task_id | over_threshold
---------------+------------+---------+---------------
VER            | 2015-10-01 |      10 |              0
FRD            | 2015-11-04 |      20 |              1
```

The date range will need to select 3 months :

- Oct-2015
- Nov-2015
- Dec-2015

The data I expect to end up with will be :

```
MonthYear | referral_group | count_of_group | total_over_threshold
----------+----------------+----------------+---------------------
Oct-2015  | VER            |              1 |                    0
Oct-2015  | FRD            |              0 |                    0
Oct-2015  | FCC            |              0 |                    0
Nov-2015  | VER            |              0 |                    0
Nov-2015  | FRD            |              1 |                    1
Nov-2015  | FCC            |              0 |                    0
Dec-2015  | VER            |              0 |                    0
Dec-2015  | FRD            |              0 |                    0
Dec-2015  | FCC            |              0 |                    0
```

DDL to create the 2 tables and populate with data is as below..

```
CREATE TABLE test_data (
referral_group char(3),
task_date date,
task_id integer,
over_threshold integer);
insert into test_data values
('VER','2015-10-01',10,1),
('FRD','2015-11-04',20,0);

CREATE TABLE referral_grouper (
referral_group char(3));
insert into referral_grouper values
('FRD'),
('VER'),
('FCC');
```

This is a very cut-down example which uses the minimal tables/columns for this example, which is why I have no primary keys/indexes.

I can get this running under LUW no problem, by using NOT EXISTS in the joins as per this SQL.

```
WITH DATERANGE(FROM_DTE,yyyymm, TO_DTE) AS
(
  SELECT DATE('2015-10-01'), YEAR('2015-10-01')*100+MONTH('2015-10-01'), '2015-12-31'
    FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
  UNION ALL
    SELECT FROM_DTE + 1 DAY, YEAR(FROM_DTE+1 DAY)*100+MONTH(FROM_DTE+1 DAY), TO_DTE
    FROM DATERANGE
    WHERE FROM_DTE &lt; TO_DTE
)
select
  referral_grouper.referral_group,
  daterange.yyyymm,
  count(test_data.task_id) AS total_count,
  COALESCE(SUM(over_threshold),0) AS total_over_threshold
FROM
  test_data
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN daterange ON (daterange.from_dte=test_data.task_date OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM daterange d2 WHERE d2.from_dte=test_data.task_date))
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN referral_grouper ON (referral_grouper.referral_group=test_data.referral_group OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM referral_grouper g2 WHERE g2.referral_group=test_data.referral_group))
GROUP BY
  referral_grouper.referral_group,
  daterange.yyyymm
```

However... This needs to work on ZOS, and under ZOS you cannot use subqueries with EXISTS in a join. Removing the NOT EXISTS means the non existing rows no longer show up.

There must be a way to write the SQL to return all rows from the 2 linking tables without using NOT EXISTS, but I just cannot seem to find it. Any help with this would be very appreciated as it has me stumped

Comment: I don't think you even need those `NOT EXISTS` at all since you're using outer joins.

Comment: I had tried that but the results are quite unpredictable. It misses some of the months where no data exists, and also has records with null monthname/yyyymm.

Comment: ok I have it working. I removed the OR NOT EXISTS from daterange, and altered the join on referral_grouper to be just a normal [inner] JOIN. Under ZOS this allows the NOT EXISTS subquery, and it seems to work and the figures are correct. Why this works and not the RIGHT OUTER JOIN without the EXISTS is a mystery

Comment: @jimnz111 - you can answer your own question, y'know.  To avoid headaches, you should generally make the `FROM` table reference that will "always" (pretty much) be there - in this case likely `daterange` - and _then_ get optional connections (if any), usually via `LEFT JOIN`.  [Something like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/96df7/12/0).  Oh, I _really_ recommend creating a permanent Calendar File, which is a greatly expanded version, having all sorts of joinable/searchable goodness.